# Firefox won't display first row in a dynamically generated JSON table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynamic, append

Using the jQuery code below, I'm trying to take a JSON object to create a new table populated with all the JSON data.  The code below works perfectly in every browser except for Firefox.  In Firefox, the code does create the table, but it consistently skips over the first row. (All the remaining rows display perfectly in FF.)  More precisely, during the first iteration of the "each" method, the code does create the  tags for the first row along with an id attribute for that  tag. However, none of the inner HTML (the  elements and text) is appended to the  element.  I can't understand why the code works in every browser (including IE8) but not FF.  Can anyone offer some suggestions?

```
$('#mydiv').append('<table><thead><th>Activity</th><th>Category</th><th>Deadline</th><th>Status</th></thead><tbody>')

$(json).each(function(i) {
    $('#mydiv tbody')
        .append("<tr id='" + json[i].id + "'></tr>")
        .children("'#" + json[i].id + "'")
            .append("<td class='activity'>"  + json[i].activity + "</td>")
            .append("<td class='category'>"  + json[i].category  + "</td>")
            .append("<td class='deadline'>"  + json[i].deadline  + "</td>")
            .append("<td class='status'>"    + json[i].status    + "</td>")
})
$('#mydiv').append('</tbody></table>')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (not sure it'll work..)

```
$('#mydiv').append('<table><thead><th>Activity</th><th>Category</th><th>Deadline</th><th>Status</th></thead><tbody></tbody></table>')

$(json).each(function(i) {
    $('#mydiv tbody')
        .append(
            $("<tr />").attr("id", json[i].id)
            .append("<td class='activity'>"  + json[i].activity + "</td>")
            .append("<td class='category'>"  + json[i].category  + "</td>")
            .append("<td class='deadline'>"  + json[i].deadline  + "</td>")
            .append("<td class='status'>"    + json[i].status    + "</td>")
        )
});
```

Comment: It worked! Can you explain why my code didn't work in FF (and only FF) while your suggestion did?  I'd vote up your answer if I could, but I don't have the reputation yet.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but when you append the first line, the HTML becomes incomplete, so I think different browsers try to "complete" it in different ways. (I think you can still mark this as a "correct answer", even if you can't upvote)